# Modificar archivo .txt

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int score, score_temp;
    char player_name_temp, player_name, player_letter;
    int i;
    FILE *stream == NULL;

stream = fopen("scores_data.txt", "r+");
        if (stream == NULL)
            printf("ERROR: No fue posible abrir el archivo");
        while (feof(stream) == 0){
            fseek(stream, sizeof(int), SEEK_END);
            fread(&score_temp, sizeof(int), sizeof(int), stream);
            if (score > score_temp){
                printf("FELICIDADES!!!, entraste al TOP 10 de los mejores jugadores\n");
                printf("Ingrese 4 caracteres\n");
                for (i=0; i<4; i++){
                    printf("Letra %d: ", i+1);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%c", &player_letter);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    player_name[i] = player_letter;
                }

                fwrite(&player_name, 1, sizeof (player_name), stream);
                fwrite(&score, sizeof (int), sizeof(score), stream);

                //fprintf(stream, "%s %d", player_name, score);
            }
        }

return 0;
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer en este pedazo de código es modificar un archivo.txt , el archivo es el siguiente:

```
XXXX 9
XXXX 8
XXXX 7
XXXX 6
XXXX 5
XXXX 4
XXXX 3
XXXX 2
XXXX 1
XXXX 0
```

Quiero cambiar completamente un renglón, digamos que score = 10, entonces en el if (score > score_temp) entra, y me voy a posicionar en principio del archivo porque 10>9, sin embargo me gustaría realizar la comparación desde lo más abajo del archivo, para ello estoy intentando usar fseek y fread

```
fseek(stream, sizeof(int), SEEK_END);
fread(&score_temp, sizeof(int), sizeof(int), stream);
```

y una vez encontrada la posición del archivo donde se reescribirán los datos, pues quiero modificar completamente el renglon XXXX n con los nuevos datos tomados.
Esto es pues una tabla de puntuaciones como la de un juego arcade, sé que mi código tiene errores lógicos al momento de decidir el renglón (si es que lo está haciendo), pero actualmente eso es lo de menos ;.;
Solo me gustaría saber como saber como posicionarme en cierta parte del archivo y modificar todo un renglón del mismo, gracias. T. T

Comment: La verdad mejor te recomendaría hacer algo más simple, recuperar todo el archivo y modificarlo a tu antojo para luego reemplazar el viejo archivo con el nuevo.

Comment: Y con que funciones se haría eso?, no se si también sería mejor ponerle un numero al inicio en forma de indice a cada renglón del archivo para facilitar el uso del mismo

Comment: Solo reserva una cadena de variables, algo como: puntuacion[10] y guarda en el todas las puntuaciones del 1 al 10 que están en el archivo, y modificalos si es necesario, luego guarda los resultados sobre el viejo archivo de puntuaciones.